# How to serve Tensorflow2 Image Segmentation model with Base64 in Google Clound AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm successfully able to save and deploy a TF2 Image segmentation model to AI Platform with the following code:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None), dtype=tf.string)])
def serving(input_image):

    # Convert bytes of jpeg input to float32 tensor for model
    def _input_to_feature(image_bytes):
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_bytes, channels=3)
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32) / 255.0
        img = tf.image.resize_with_pad(img, 256, 256)
        return img
    img = tf.map_fn(_input_to_feature, input_image, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Predict
    pred = model(img)

    def _pred_to_image(pred):
        pred = tf.cast(pred * 255, dtype=tf.uint8)

        img_str = tf.image.encode_png(pred, compression=-1, name=None)
        return img_str

    img_str = tf.map_fn(_pred_to_image, pred, dtype=tf.string)

    return img_str


tf.saved_model.save(model, export_dir=checkpoint_dir+'/saved_model', signatures=serving)
```

However I get this error while sending request like this:

```
img_str = base64.b64encode(open('sample_372.jpg', "rb").read()).decode()
response = service.projects().predict(name=name,body={'instances': [img_str]}).execute()
```

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nerveblox-268109/models/femoral/versions/v6:predict?alt=json returned "{ "error": "Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with \'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB\'\n\t [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]" }">
```

Anybody had a similar issue like this? it seems like a problem with `tf.image.decode_jpeg`. I also tried with `tf.image.decode_image` and got a similar error. I can use `tf.image.decode_jpeg` with my local Base64 encoding, so this function should be able to work but somehow it's not receiving the same input in the server!

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of experimentations (due to limited and outdated documentation of Tensorflow) , I realized that in order for the serving function to decode Base64, the request should be sent like this: `{'instances': [{'b64': image_base64}]}`. Also `convert_image_dtype` scales the data to [0,1] by itself so /255.0 should not be done. Also `map_fn` only works on CPU so it should be used with `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):`. Finaly and the most annoying part is the encoding to Base64. `tf.io.encode_base64` is the only way I found in Tensorflow to encode to Base64 but it encodes to web-safe, meaning that it replaces \ and + to _ and - in order to work in URL. But the Google API Client only accepts normal Base64 encoding. So I had to reverse this by regualr expressions. Here's the updated serving function:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None), dtype=tf.string)])
def serving(input_image):

    # Convert bytes of jpeg input to float32 tensor for model
    def _input_to_feature(img_bytes):
        img = tf.image.decode_image(img_bytes, channels=3)
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
        img = tf.image.resize_with_pad(img, 256, 256)
        return img

    # Preprocessing
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        img = tf.map_fn(_input_to_feature, input_image, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Prediction
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        pred = model(img)
        colors = tf.constant([[0.2, 0.3, 0.4]])
        pred_rgb = tf.tensordot(pred, colors, axes=1)

    def _pred_to_image(pred):
        pred = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(pred,dtype=tf.uint8)

        pred_str = tf.image.encode_png(pred, compression=4)
        pred_encoded = tf.io.encode_base64(pred_str, pad=True)
        pred_encoded = tf.strings.regex_replace(pred_encoded, '_', '/')
        pred_encoded = tf.strings.regex_replace(pred_encoded, '-', '+')

        return pred_encoded

    # Postprocessing
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        img_str = tf.map_fn(_pred_to_image, pred_rgb, dtype=tf.string)

    return img_str


tf.saved_model.save(model, export_dir=checkpoint_dir+'/saved_model', signatures=serving)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized it also works without `tf.map_fn` like this,

```
# Prediction
with tf.device('/gpu'):
    img = tf.image.decode_image(input_image[0], channels=3)

    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    pred = model(img)[0]
    colors = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0],
                          [1., 0, 0],
                          [0, 1., 0],
                          [0, 0, 1.],
                          [1., 1., 0]
                         ])
    pred_rgb = tf.tensordot(pred, colors, axes=1)

    not_background = pred[...,0][...,None] < 0.9
    transparency = tf.cast(not_background, dtype=tf.float32)*0.3

    rgba = tf.concat((pred_rgb, transparency), axis=-1)
    rgba = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(rgba, dtype=tf.uint8)

    pred_str = tf.image.encode_png(rgba, compression=5)
    pred_encoded = tf.io.encode_base64(pred_str, pad=True)
    pred_encoded = tf.strings.regex_replace(pred_encoded, '_', '/')
    pred_encoded = tf.strings.regex_replace(pred_encoded, '-', '+')
    pred_encoded = tf.expand_dims(pred_encoded, axis=0)

return pred_encoded
```